# C doesn't have a bool? Also VS2010 question

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm using VS 2010 Pro.

First, C doesn't have a bool type?  I just have to use int with 0/1.  Seems odd as most languages consider boolean a standard type.

Also I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro but doesn't have a "C Project".  I just created an Empty C++ Project.   The file names end with .c

The problem with this is the keywords are messed up (shows bool as highlighted/valid in the editor, but compiler doesn't like it).

I went to repair/add components and they have C#, F#, C++, Visual Basic; but no C?

Comment: For those coming to the question who have VS2013 or later, `bool` is now supported via `stdbool.h`. I'm not sure about support in VS2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Newest C standard (C99) has bool type indeed. Just include `stdbool.h` and you can use it. Unfortunately MSVC does not haver proper support for C at all. Only partial C89.

Comment: You mean `stdbool.h`. Anyway OP is using MSVC which does not support the C language, much less "newest C standard"...

Comment: @R: MSVC supports C (C90), just not C99.

Comment: `bool` is a typedef. The predefined type is `_Bool`.

Comment: @Nemanja: It does not. `wprintf(L"%s", "hello world\n");` is part of the C language which does not work on MSVC.

Comment: Yeah he should switch to proper C compiler (GCC) or stick with C++ which has bool type too.

Comment: @R: that's part of C99, but not C90. I just re-checked the standard, (hardcopy -- what a pain) and it doesn't list wprintf at all.

Comment: @R: Try wprintf with gcc (without the "-std=c99" option)

Comment: So MSVC sucks for C?  What's a good compiler/IDE on windows for C code?

Comment: I find R.'s `wprintf()` example interesting. Definitely non-standard behavior (intentionally so by Microsoft).  It makes sense for how MS implemented their 'ANSI'/'UNICODE' platforms and build techniques way back when. But it is definitely not standard compliant. By the way, `wprintf()` wasn't originally in C90, it was added 1995's Amendment 1 (I think). I have no idea what level of support MS claims for the 1995 amendment.

Comment: @user697111 Definately `GCC`. Here are some good IDEs: [`Code::Blocks`](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and [`Codelite`](http://www.codelite.org/). Both comes with integrated MinGW GCC.

Comment: @Athabaska - a bit of trivia: while MinGW has much better C99 support that MSVC, it'll also fail R.'s `wprintf()` example because MinGW relies heavily on the MSVCRT.DLL runtime...

Comment: @Michael Burr OP was asking for proper Compiler & IDE for C and I gave him some suggestions. As for the widechar support, it is too broken to be useful. As far as I know upcoming C++0x and C9X standards are trying to fix some of the wchar issues.

Comment: @Athabaska: I wasn't saying your comment was in any way a bad idea - just a bit of trivia (given R.'s previous example).  Also, I had never heard of Codelite before - I'll have to check it out.  So, thanks for that! (last time I looked at Code::Blocks - admittedly a long, long time ago - it was too sluggish to make me happy).

Answer (score 6):

The current C language (C99) has a `bool` type (actually `_Bool`, but including `stdbool.h` declares a `typedef` alias `bool` for it), but since you're using MSVC, that's not available to you. In any case, using boolean types in C is completely non-idiomatic and largely useless. Just use `int` like everyone else. Or if you need a giant array of them, make your own bit-array implementation.

Comment: +1 for non-idiomatic and useless! Even the `is*` functions in C99 do not return `_Bool`s.

Comment: "using boolean types in C is completely non-idiomatic and largely useless" - a bit like `short`.

Comment: It makes the code a lot more readable to use booleans instead of integers. Recent versions of MSVC added support for bool in C code.

Answer (score 2):

C did not have an actual Boolean type until C99.

As a result, idiomatic C doesn't really use boolean-valued symbols or expressions as such (i.e., you won't see many explicit tests against "true" or "false").  Instead, any zero-valued integral expression or a NULL pointer will evaluate to "false", and any non-zero-valued integral expression or a non-NULL pointer will evaluate to "true". So you'll see a lot of code like:

```
foo *bar = malloc(sizeof *bar * ...);
if (bar) // equivalent to writing bar != NULL
{
   // bar is non-NULL
}
```

Relational and equality expressions such as `a == b` or `c < d` will evaluate to an integral type with a value of either 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Some people introduce their own TRUE or FALSE symbolic constants by doing something like

```
#define TRUE  (1)  // or (!FALSE), or (1==1), or...
#define FALSE (0)  // or (!TRUE), or (1==0), or ...
```

Unforunately, some of those people occasionally manage to misspell 0 or 1 (or the expressions that are supposed to evaluate to 0 or 1); I once spent an afternoon chasing my tail because someone screwed up and dropped a header where TRUE == FALSE.

Not coincidentally, that was the day I stopped using symbolic constants for Boolean values altogether.

Answer (score 2):

[See R.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680340/c-doesnt-have-a-bool-also-vs2010-question/5680401#5680401) for information about the `bool` type.

Unfortunately, MSVC doesn't support C99 when it's compiling C code - it has bits and pieces (generally things in the C99 library that are required by C++), but for the most part it only supports C90.

As for `bool` still being highlighted in the editor - the highlighting in MSVC may be sophisticated, but it doesn't take into account the differentiation between C, C++, and C++/CLI.  For example, if you use a construct that's CLI-only, it'll be highlighted as such even if your project has nothing to do with CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the bool type:
In C, any non-zero value is regarded as "true" (and zero is "false").  This comes in handy when, say, checking the value of a pointer:

```
if ((ptr = malloc(sizeof(foo))) != 0) ...
```

can be shortened to:

if (ptr = malloc(sizeof(foo))) ...

C was designed to be a "mid-level" language, i.e. in-between assembler and traditional "high-level" languages.  It was also designed to be compact/concise.  So it has a minimalist flavor, exemplified in the its support for "shorthand" like the above, and also in the omission of a built-in Boolean data type (up to C99, as others have pointed out).

Many libraries/frameworks (ones that I'm aware of anyway) do something like the following

```
#define BOOL int
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE (!FALSE)
```

This does mean that you should avoid directly comparing values/results to TRUE.  Consider the following.  Given `int a = 2; int b = 3;`, then both `if (a)` and `if (b)` evaluate to true, but `a` and `b` are not equal.

Concerning syntax highlighting:
C++ does have a bool type, which I'm guessing is why the compiler highlights the word.  However, the fact that your source file ends it .c marks it as C code, so the type isn't allowed.
Seems like the syntax highlighting should catch this, though.

Concerning the absence of C components:
If I understand the question correctly: the short answer is, in order to do "managed code" (ie .NET) development -- which is what you'd have to be doing  in order to use .NET components -- you need to use a language supported by the .NET runtime, i.e. C#, VB(.NET), F#, or C++.
(C++ is available in both "managed" and "unmanaged" flavors, meaning you can develop either against .NET or the Windows API.)

Are you under some sort of directive to use C as opposed to other languages?

Comment: I'm using C because I want to learn it and OpenGL (which is also C).  I'll probably move to C++ once I learn a bit more?  I'm experienced with java.

Comment: I'm sure you've been told this but you would probably be more comfortable in C#.  There are OpenGL wrappers for C# eg
http://www.opentk.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing in C, I'd recommend a different compiler as VC++ is not a modern C compilier and does not support the C99 standard. If you're on windows try MinGW, which basically gets you GCC with access to Windows-y API stuff.

If you're set on using Visual Studio, create your own header file to use instead of stdbool.h:

```
#pragma once

#define false   0
#define true    1

#define bool int
```

I found that Visual Studio 2010 complained if I tried to use a `typedef` instead of a `#define` to define `bool`.