# static bool function not compiling in MSVC but compiles in GCC fine

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, visual-c++, gcc

I am working with C and Postgres and we are using the Postgres API's to create some internal C functions.

I have gotten everything to compile fine, but I was hoping someone could offer explanation as to why the following function did not compile in MSVC but it compiled fine in GCC:

Function Declaration:

```
static bool func1(const u_char *src, int length);
```

### Errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'func1'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

In order to get it to compile, I changed it from static bool to static int. (Since they are equivalent in C). Now it works fine.

static bool compiled fine in gcc. Is there somthing gcc does under the hood to make this syntax proper? Or is this a bug with MSVC?

Compiler Info:

All builds are 64 bit

Visual Studio 2010 Professional

gcc 4.4.7

Additional info:

I have the project set to "Compile as C code"

I am compiling this into a DLL.

### SOLUTION

[This is a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680340/c-doesnt-have-a-bool-also-vs2010-question)

In short, MSVC does not support C very well. bool is not a datatype in C in versions before C99. MSVC only supports C89.

Changing from bool to int gets around this specific issue just fine.

Comment: Which MSVC version are you using?

Comment: Sorry andreas, I was doing edits to add that in. I had hit enter by accident before i was done with the question. Let me edit it in really quick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C doesn't have a bool? Also VS2010 question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680340/c-doesnt-have-a-bool-also-vs2010-question) or [trying to use '#include <stdbool.h>' in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548521/trying-to-use-include-stdbool-h-in-vs-2010)

Comment: Alright, the question is actually finished now.

Comment: Totally a duplicate. I looked and looked for a duplicate for this question too.
I voted to close the question as well.
Thanks Andreas.